# How to install ANDROID_SDK_ROOT on Mac OS?

Tags: android, macos, cordova, android-sdk-manager

Good day. I can not understand how to install ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable for the Mac OS.

Search on stackoverflow already made, the code on recommendations tried to use - nothing.

I installed Android Studio by standard, my SDK has path `/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/`

```
vim ~/.bash_profile

export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/admin/.android/avd

source ~/.bash_profile
```

When you try to build an application in Cordova the same result:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 13.0.1
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, after configuring your `.bash_profile` be sure to open a new terminal session so the environmental variables get picked up.

Assuming you've tried that already, you may want to consider installing the Android development kit through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) - a package manager for MacOS. Once you have everything set up there, you can then run

`$ brew install gradle`

`$ brew install android-sdk`

Homebrew will then add the appropriate variables to your `.bash_profile`

If that all still proves to be of no avail, try setting your `JAVA_HOME` variable to be:

`export JAVA_HOME="$(/ur/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Similar information already met, but why that did not work. Now it seems to work.

I apologize that I did not write earlier-was engaged in development... =)